# Как здесь расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

О том как это сделать, мы расскажем несколько позже.

Поэтому для того чтобы получить от должника денежные средства или иное имущество, взыскателю будет необходимо приложить определенные усилия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) "О том, как это сделать, мы расскажем несколько позже".

СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, указательное слово О ТОМ входит в главную часть.

2) "Поэтому, для того чтобы получить от должника денежные средства или иное имущество, взыскателю будет необходимо приложить определенные усилия".

Расчленение составного подчинительного союза связано с наличием наречия ПОЭТОМУ. Это правило стараются соблюдать, но в некоторых случаях оно кажется формальным и встречаются варианты без расчленения, например: "И поэтому для того чтобы вырасти в духовной жизни, познать глубину того опыта в познании Бога, который мы обычно называем верой, надо научиться жить так, как советует Бог".

Дело в том, что смысловые акценты при расчленении союза смещаются. Нерасчлененный союз – это чисто союзная связь предложений, а расчлененный союз  напоминает местоименно-союзную связь с тесным взаимодействием главной и придаточной части.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно будет так: "О том, как это сделать, мы расскажем несколько позже".
"Поэтому для того, чтобы получить от должника средства или иное имущество, взыскателю..."
То есть, у Вас было пропущено две запятые.